# Python split by comma delimiter and strip

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to open a file in python in read mode then write  striped and split data to an output file. I am unsure how to split and strip the same data. Do I need to create a different line? Do I need to write the data out first? The code has both but I get an error.

What I currently have

```
input_file = open(inpath,"r")
lines = input_file.readlines()
for line in lines.split(','):
    line = line.strip()
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: list' object has no attribute 'split
```

Comment: `lines` is a list, you can't split a list

Comment: you can post a example of the content of file and the expected output?

Comment: workingDirec = raw_input("What is the working directory?")
original_file = raw_input("The input filename is?")
full_original = os.path.join(workingDirec,original_file)
chi_square = raw_input("The name of the chi-squared stats table file is?")
full_chi_square = os.path.join(workingDirec,chi_square)
output_file = raw_input ("What is the output filename?")
full_output = os.path.join(workingDirec,output_file)

Comment: above are the strings that I am running to request a directory from a user and input file. Once I have that data, I am trying to write the data to separate list that has been split by a comma and stripped of all white space

Comment: you can edit the question and add the code in the question description, is more easy to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
for line in lines:
    for value in line.split(','):
        value = value.strip()
```

Hope it helps.